# NDK - Image thresholding

Tags: c++, image-processing, android-ndk, java-native-interface, threshold

I want to perform a double hysterisis thresholding.
I pass the bitmap as a parameter, and then I threshold it to return it back to android.
my native code is:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <android/bitmap.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>


#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

typedef struct {

    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t alpha;
} argb;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_mypakage_MainActivity_Hysterisis
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject bmp){

        AndroidBitmapInfo  infocolor;
        void*              pixelscolor;
        int                ret;
        int             y;
        int             x;
        uint32_t *pixel;


        if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bmp, &infocolor)) < 0) {
            return;
        }

        if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bmp, &pixelscolor)) < 0) {
        }


        pixel = (uint32_t *) pixelscolor;

            uint32_t p,ac,bc,cc,dc,ec,fc,gc,hc;
            bool again = true;
            while (again) {
                again=false;
                for (y=1;y<=infocolor.height - 1;y++) {
                    for (x=1;x<infocolor.width -1;x++) {
                        p = (uint32_t) ( (*(pixel + x + (y ) * infocolor.stride)));


                        if (p == 0xFF888888) {
                            ac = (uint32_t) ( (*(pixel + x -1 + (y -1 ) * infocolor.stride)));
                            bc = (uint32_t) ( (*(pixel + x + (y -1 ) * infocolor.stride)));
                            cc = (uint32_t) ( (*(pixel + x +1 + (y -1 ) * infocolor.stride)));
                            dc = (uint32_t) ( (*(pixel + x +1 + (y ) * infocolor.stride)));
                            ec = (uint32_t) ( (*(pixel + x +1 + (y+1 ) * infocolor.stride)));
                            fc = (uint32_t) ( (*(pixel + x + (y +1 ) * infocolor.stride)));
                            fc = (uint32_t) ( (*(pixel + x -1 + (y +1 ) * infocolor.stride)));
                            fc = (uint32_t) ( (*(pixel + x -1 + (y ) * infocolor.stride)));
                            if (ac ==0xFFFFFFFF || bc ==0xFFFFFFFF || cc ==0xFFFFFFFF || dc ==0xFFFFFFFF
                                    || ec ==0xFFFFFFFF || fc ==0xFFFFFFFF || gc ==0xFFFFFFFF || hc ==0xFFFFFFFF) {
                                ( (*(pixel + x + (y ) * infocolor.stride)))= 0xFFFFFFFF;
                                again=true;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

      for (y=1;y<=infocolor.height - 1;y++) {
            for (x=1;x<infocolor.width -1;x++) {
                p = (uint32_t) ( (*(pixel + x + (y ) * infocolor.stride)));
                if (p == 0xFF888888) {
                    ( (*(pixel + x + (y ) * infocolor.stride)))= 0xFF000000;
                }

            }
        }


        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bmp);
}
```

My problem is that the app crashes with the following error:

```
A/libc(29191): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at ...
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop termination conditions are different for x and y. For y, you should iterate while `< infocolor.height - 1`, so that the last y value is equal to `infocolor.height - 2`, which means that when you add 1 to y you will address `infocolor.height - 1`, which is the maximum y value before you go out of range.

Change it to:

```
for (y=1;y<infocolor.height - 1;y++)
```

Also, the stride is the number of bytes per row, not the number of pixels, so you will need to divide by 4:

```
int pixelsPerRow = infocolor.stride / 4;

ac = (uint32_t) ( (*(pixel + x -1 + (y -1 ) * pixelsPerRow)));
```

etc

Comment: changed it, same problem

Comment: I've edited my answer, the stride calculations also need to change

Comment: the app doesn't crash anymore. But the algorithm is not doing what is intended to do. I.e I still have the gray pixels. I placed some LOG inside the `if (p == 0xFF888888)` , It isn't printed.

Comment: Check that `infocolor.format` is `ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888`. And check that the grey pixels are actually 0xff888888 and not 0xf808080 or some other value. Also, there is a potential bug in your code in that you are writing to the bitmap as you are reading from it. So you will set a pixel to 0xffffffff and then read it in the next iteration as fc, and you will propagate the white color across the entire row. Try writing to a second bitmap instead of one you are reading from.

Comment: How can I contact you? I'm currently working on translating an edge detection algo to ndk, already implemented in android/java. but it is slow. now that the hysterisis is working in native with great performance boost! I want to translate the other parts like non-maxima suppression.

Comment: You can add another comment under here and I'll see it. Or ping me with @samgak in any comment on the site. Good luck with your project.